# How can I find the zsh function associated with a zle widget?

Tags: zsh, zle

I'm messing around with the `accept-line` widget and not getting the results I want. 
I want to inspect (and log) what is happening to accept-line by finding the underlying zsh function.

My understanding is that zle widgets exist in their own separate namespace with the operation `zle -N` mapping keys to value in this namespace and the operation `zle -A` duplicating mappings.

I had quite a detailed search of of the *zshzle* manual page and did some googling but the best I could come up with is the following that makes use the `zle -l` operation.

```
zle -l  | grep '^accept-line ' | grep -Eo '\(.*\)' | tr -d '()'
```

Is there anything that doesn't depend so directly on the format of the output of `zle -l`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a special array called `widgets` which holds names of all widgets and functions associated to them, so try

```
echo $widgets[accept-line]
```

Be aware however that some widgets are defined internally and all you will get is a word **builtin**, but judging from your *grep* command some script sourced in *.zshrc* overwrote that widget, so you should get meaningful result.

BTW, if you want to list all available widgets and their functions use `(kv)` flag:

```
echo ${(kv)widgets}
```

Comment: That's what I was after. Some digging shows that although `$widgets` is not documented in the `zle` manual it is documented `zshmodules` (a manual page describing various zsh extension modules)